# Migrating from JSP to Freemarker

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, freemarker

I'm working on a Spring 2.5 project where four different webapps have duplicate JSPs (they were all derivations of the same webapp).  I want to introduce Freemarker so I can externalize and reuse these templates across all the webapps.  However, I want to approach this iteratively since it's going to be a big project, so I need JSP and Freemarker to live in harmony for awhile.

I know Spring allows chaining multiple ViewResolvers, but JSP's [InternalResourceViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/index.html?org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.html) and Freemarker's [FreeMarkerViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/index.html?org/springframework/web/servlet/view/freemarker/FreeMarkerViewResolver.html) both state that they need to be last in the chain.  I've tried to chain them anyways and specify an order priority, but no luck.

Freemarker seems to support JSPs to some degree, though I don't really see how I could use that in a gradual migration (http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_misc_servlet.html).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: In Spring 2.5 you'll probably have to use a BeanNameResolver since you can't have two URL resolvers, see [this thread](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-66115.html). This got much easier in 3.0 where you can order resolvers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction.  This put the fire under my feet to upgrade our codebase to Spring 3 (less than an hour - thanks Spring!).  Chaining the resolvers worked as I expected now.  Thanks again!

Comment: Cool; yeah, the upgrade option brings several benefits, resolvers being one of them :) Glad you worked it out.

Comment: Dave Newton - you should add your suggestion as an answer, to allow Stano accept it and ensure others can benefit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Spring 2.5 you'll probably have to use a BeanNameResolver since you can't have two URL resolvers, see [this thread](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-66115.html). This got much easier in 3.0 where you can order resolvers.

**References**

- [NixMash Post: The Move from Velocity to FreeMarker with Spring Boot](http://nixmash.com/post/the-move-from-velocity-to-freemarker-with-spring-boot)
- [A Review of Java Template Engines - DZone Web Dev](https://dzone.com/articles/template-engines-at-one-spring-boot-and-engines-se)